# How do we compute |G| = |Ox| · |Gx|?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was given a set X and a group G and was asked to find Gx and Xg. Then I was asked to find the G-equivalence class of X for each of the G-sets which is the orbit Ox but i'm having trouble verifying the equation below.

For each x ∈ X verify that |G| = |Ox| · |Gx|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic assumption is that $\;|G|<\infty\;$ , of course.

Using the notation $\;H/G\;$ to denote the set of left cosets of the subgroup $\;H\;$ in $\;G\;$ , define a map

$$f:\mathcal O(x)\to G_x/G\;,\;\;f(gx):=gG_x$$

Note that

$$gx=hx\implies h^{-1}gx=x\implies h^{-1}g\in G_x\implies f(gx)=gG_x=hG_x=f(hx)$$

so the above shows the map is well defined **and also** that it is injective (why? Check we can reverse the implication arrows above).

Finally, since the map is clearly subjective, we get

$$\left|\mathcal O(x)\right|=[G:G_x]=\frac{|G|}{|G_x|}$$

and we're done.